# How to tell the Intel Debugger which program to run and which arguments to use at the command line?

Tags: debugging, intel

I'm a regular user of the Intel Debugger (right now version 13.0 in Ubuntu 12.10). I normally load the executable to debug and its arguments from the GUI itself, but I am trying to find a way to pass that information to the debugger from the command line. Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I don't see the way to do it at the manual.

The shell script that actually launches the GUI calls:
java -jar $INSTALLDIR/debugger/gui/intel64/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -showsplash -gui -native $TTY $IDB_ARGUMENTS&

so I know that I can pass options to the GUI itself, but I don't know which ones or their format.

Any help?

Thanks,
Ángel de Vicente

Answer (score 0):

idb -args ./mancha2D_paramesh.x mancha.trol 
works, but I had overlooked it, as it gives some errors:

```
idb -args ./mancha2D_paramesh.x mancha.trol
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/bin/intel64/idb: 68: [: -args: unexpected operator
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/bin/intel64/idb: 68: [: ./mancha2D_paramesh.x: unexpected operator
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013.1.117/bin/intel64/idb: 68: [: mancha.trol: unexpected operator
```

The errors go away if I run it with bash instead of sh.